# How to Validate array arguments and returning int

Tags: c#, .net

The contents of this question have been removed due to a DMCA Takedown request by Codility Limited

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow is not a homework code writing service.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's no longer usefully answerable now that it's entire content has been DMCA-ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your case is a typical **F**inite **S**tate **M**achine. First, let's extract *model*, i.e.
validation rules:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<string, bool>> m_Validators =
  new Dictionary<string, Func<string, bool>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    { "--name", x => x != null && x.Length >= 3 && x.Length <= 10},
    { "--count", x => x != null && 
                      int.TryParse(x, out int v) && 
                      v >= 10 && v <= 100},
    { "--help", null},
};
```

Then we can easily implement FSM:

```
public int Validate(string[] args) {
  if (null == args)
    return -1; // we're asked not to throw exceptions

  HashSet<string> commands = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; ++i) {
    if (!m_Validators.TryGetValue(args[i], out var validator))
      return -1; // unknown command (--name, --count, --help expected)

    // If command appears two or more times we return -1, e.g.
    // --name ABC --count 34 --name Other
    // If you accept duplicates, put just
    // commands.Add(args[i]);
    if (!commands.Add(args[i]))
      return -1;

    if (null != validator) {
      if (i >= args.Length - 1)
        return -1; // --name or --count are the last operators

      if (!validator(args[++i]))
        return -1; // validation falure, e.g. --count abcd
    }
  }

  // validation has been passed; check if we have --help
  return commands.Contains("--help") ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: When the right argument is passed but with no value to check the return is 0, like { "--name", "--help"} ; 

I added one more check if the index after the argument starts with --  to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

Got a new nice project today, so I'm in the mood of doing someone else a favour. Even if that some one won't benefit from that in terms of making progress and improving his own C# skills by sponging internet code, but never mind

```
       public int Validate(string[] args) {
    
      bool expectNumber = false, expectName = false,
              foundHelp = false, foundCount = false, foundName = false;
      
      foreach(arg in args) {
        
         if(expectNumber) {
            
            if (!int.TryParse(arg, our var number) || number < 10 || number > 100) {
               return -1;
            }
            
            expectNumber = false;
         }
         else if (expectName ) {
            
            if (arg == null || arg.Length < 3 || arg.Length > 10) {
               return -1;
            }
             
            expectName = false;
         }
         else {
            switch (arg) {
                
                case "--name":
                   if (foundName) {//disallow multiple "--name"
                      return -1;    
                   }
                   expectName = true;
                   foundName = true;
                   break;
                   
                case "--count":
                   if (foundCount) {//disallow multiple "--count"
                      return -1;    
                   }
                   expectNumber = true;
                   foundCount = true;
                   break;
                   
                case "--help":
                   if (foundHelp) { //disallow multiple "--help"
                      return -1;    
                   }
                   foundHelp = true;
                   result = 1;
                   break;
                   
                default:
                   return -1; //unrecognized arg
           }
        }
    }
    return (expectNumber || expectName) ? -1 : result;
}
```